# Метод compareDocumentPosition JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста понять принцип compareDocumentPosition().

Экспериментировал в консоли:

```
var div=document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML="<span><span><span><span><span>span</span></span></span></span></span>
div.appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
```

Получилось вот что:

```
<div>
  ​<span>
    ​<span>
      ​<span>
        ​<span>
          ​<span>"s"​</span>​
        </span>
      ​</span>
    ​</span>​
  </span>
  ​<p>​</p>
​</div>​
```

Теперь применяю `nodeA.compareDocumentPosition(nodeB)`

```
r = div.childNodes[0].compareDocumentPosition(div.childNodes[1])//r=4 r.toString(2)="100"
```

Здесь все понятно, nodeA предшествует nodeB

Но вот в следующем результат уже мне не понятен

```
r1 = div.childNodes[0].compareDocumentPosition(div) //r1=10 r1.toString(2)="1010"
r2 = div.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].compareDocumentPosition(div) //r2=10 r2.toString(2)="1010"
```

Собственно вопрос. Почему результат 10 а не 8 (nodeB содержит nodeA), и что значит 10? Так же, результаты `r1` и `r2` не должны ли быть разными? (уровень вложенности же разный)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Вопрос*: `Почему результат 10 а не 8 (nodeB содержит nodeA), и что значит 10?`
*Ответ*:

> Метод **compareDocumentPosition** – 
>   предоставляет одновременно информацию и о содержании и об
>   относительном порядке элементов.
>
> ```
> Биты        Число     Значение
> 000000        0       nodeA и nodeB -- один и тот же узел
> 000001        1       Узлы в разных документах (или один из них не в документе)
> 000010        2       nodeB предшествует nodeA (в порядке обхода документа)
> 000100        4       nodeA предшествует nodeB
> 001000        8       nodeB содержит nodeA
> 010000        16      nodeA содержит nodeB
> 100000        32      Зарезервировано для браузера
> ```
>
> Понятие «предшествует» – означает не только «предыдущий сосед при
>   общем родителе», но и имеет более общий смысл: "раньше встречается в
>   порядке прямого обхода дерева документа.

Результат `1010` означает, что узел предшествует и одновременно содержит.

---

*Вопрос*: результаты r1 и r2 не должны ли быть разными? (уровень вложенности же разный)
*Ответ*: проверка осуществляется на факт вложенности, а не на глубину вложенности. поэтому нет, результат различаться не должен.

Источник: [compareDocumentPosition](https://learn.javascript.ru/compare-document-position)

Comment: Не вложен, а содержит

Comment: Таблицу видел, таким образом это 000010+001000=001010 правильно рассуждаю? Но почему он предшествует, он же просто вложен, или нет?

Comment: @JarryRoxwell дополнил ответ про предшествует. по поводу арифметики - да, верно

Comment: @Grundy пардоньте

Comment: А почему он считается предшествующим а не просто вложенным?

Comment: потому что рассматриваемый метод предоставляет одновременно информацию и о содержании и об относительном порядке элементов.

Comment: А существует ли метод для определения глубины вложенности?

Comment: @JarryRoxwell о таком не знаю. вероятно, для этого придётся использовать перебор/рекурсию/...